# Video Streaming Like Youtube with Advertisement Video inbetween that main video playing in Node js

Tags: node.js, youtube, video-streaming

I have to stream an video along with its advertisement video while playing the main. In between that I have to play a small advertisement video for some seconds.

Now I can streaming the main video as chunks. How can I add this small video along with that streaming?

Is there any concept is available there?

Answer (score 1):

Most ads, like YouTube, are client side. Where that is done on the player, and the server does nothing. If you intend server side ad insertion, you need to write the manifest to include the ad segments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of commercial solutions, often referring to it as SSAI or Server Side Ad Insertion. Depending on the streaming technology, it's either fairly simple or really complex.

One of the simplest formats to do it in is HLS. HLS playlist files are basically a really long playlist of individual x-second segments. You could simply add the segments of your add, somewhere in that playlist. Just remember to signal a discontinuity with #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
The discontinuity markers, basically tell the video codec, that it should expect segments that might be encoded differently.
Apple has a short guide on how to [insert ads into a playlist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/incorporating_ads_into_a_playlist).

Doing the same thing in MPEG-DASH is much more complex, and relies on what is called multi-period DASH.